# SpecFlow not listing NUnit with VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nunit, specflow

I had tried all the way on the web. 
But it still not listing NUnit in Tools -> Options -> SpecFlow test runner.
I install "NUnit Test Adapte" already.
I tried to attach NUnit but I can't find "NUnit" in available process.
Is I having wrong way to install NUnit? I downloaded the NUnit.zip and decompressed it in Program files.Did it need more steps to install it?And I also install the NUnit package in VS2013.
What's wrong did I done?Or what isn't done yet?
Please help me.

Comment: To be honest this question is impossible to answer the way it is written. You have not stated what the actual problem is. Is it that the test runner is not listed, or is it that you can't get the tests to run? Why is it a problem that the runner is not listed? I have never even looked at that config (`Tools -> Options -> SpecFlow test runner`). But in order to have any possibility of answering you should provide the correct names and links to the software you have installed and the correct full names for the nuget packages you have added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, there are too many things that could be wrong.  Here are a few suggestions you could try.

1. Verify feature files are being converted into tests.

   - How to Verify: In VS solution explorer, expand the feature file and you should see a feature.cs file.
   - Solution to fix: install the SpecFlow solution
2. Verify the test is a nunit test and not mstest

   - How to Verify: Open the feature.cs file and verify you see NUnit somewhere on that page and your scenario (no spaces) should have [TestAttribute] above it.
   - Solution to fix: Add nunit reference to the project & in the project's app.config [Add NUnit](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Configuration#unittestprovider) as the provider
3. Verify NUnit Test Adapter is installed

   - How to Verify: Write a simple nunit test & see if it shows up in the test explorer window.
   - Solution to fix: Install it or you can always [install SpecRun](http://www.specrun.net/) as an alternative.  VS Test explorer should show your tests and they can be run from there.
4. Verify all your tests are mapped

   - How to Verify: Your tests should be black except where you have variables. Hitting F12 should go to definition.
   - Solution to fix: There can be a [caching issue](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2014/08/specflow-force-step-definition-rebinding.html) but for the most part, verify the regex is correct and make sure the step definition is visible to the feature file.  That means it's either in the same project or is included in the [app.config as a known step assembly](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Configuration#stepassemblies).